# input string was not in correct format c# winform application

Tags: c#, input, datagridview

```
private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < itemgrid.RowCount - 1; i++ )
        {
            dru.insertdata("insert into tbl_godown (date,category,product,quantity,MRP,salesrate,margin,Total,vendor,unit)values('" + itemgrid.Rows[i].Cells["Column1"].Value.ToString() + "','" + itemgrid.Rows[i].Cells["Column2"].Value.ToString() + "','" + itemgrid.Rows[i].Cells["Column3"].Value.ToString() + "','" + itemgrid.Rows[i].Cells["Column4"].Value.ToString() + "','" + double.Parse(itemgrid.Rows[i].Cells["Column5"].Value.ToString()) + "','" + Convert.ToDouble(itemgrid.Rows[i].Cells["Column6"].Value.ToString()) + "','" + Convert.ToDouble(itemgrid.Rows[i].Cells["Column7"].Value.ToString()) + "','" + Convert.ToDouble(itemgrid.Rows[i].Cells["Column8"].Value.ToString()) + "','" + Convert.ToDouble(itemgrid.Rows[i].Cells["Column9"].Value.ToString()) + "','" + Convert.ToDouble(itemgrid.Rows[i].Cells["Column10"].Value.ToString()) + "') ");
            MessageBox.Show("Insert Successfully");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Inserting data from datagridview to database, the name of datagridview is itemgrid

```
private void txtquantity_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mulfunc();
}

private void txtrate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        mulfunc();
        marginfunc();
}

private void txtMRP_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        marginfunc();
}

/// <summary>
/// margin calculations(sales rate-vendor rate = margin)
/// </summary>
public void marginfunc()
{
    try
    {
        double val1;
        double val2;

        if (!double.TryParse(txtMRP.Text, out val1) || !double.TryParse(txtrate.Text, out val2))
                return;

        double val3 = val2 - val1;

        // Here you define what TextBox should show the multiplication result
        txtmargin.Text = val3.ToString();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// quantity * sales rate
/// </summary>
public void mulfunc()
{
    try 
    {
        double val1;
        double val2;

        if (!double.TryParse(txtquantity.Text, out val1) || !double.TryParse(txtrate.Text, out val2))
                return;

        double val3 = val1 * val2;

        // Here you define what TextBox should show the multiplication result
        txttotal.Text = val3.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

public void clear()
{
    cmbunit.Text = "";
    txtprod.Text = "";
    txtquantity.Text = "";
    txtMRP.Text = "";
    txtrate.Text = "";
    txtmargin.Text = "";
    txttotal.Text = "";
    txtvendor.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: Check the date format

Comment: you are inserting everything as a string(varchar or nvarchar) while some of the columns aren't strings.

Comment: What database are you using?  Your 'insert' statement is bad.

Comment: dateformat is:"yyyy-mm-dd"

Comment: What type of object is dru?

Comment: sql,can you just provide me a right insert query, it help me lot thank you

Comment: dru is object of class file, in the class file we are passing query using class file

Comment: **SQL** is just a **query language** - not a database system...... please add thte **relevant tag** for whichever **database system** you're using - `oracle`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `mysql`, `db2` or whatever else that might be ....

Comment: Why are you using a `func` suffix on all of your methods?  It's a terrible idea.`marginfunc` could be named something like `CalculateAndDisplayMargin`

Comment: ok thank you i will remember

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would not advise building dynamic SQL to perform INSERTs in this way, as this poses a risk of SQL Injection (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  But if your code is non-production (I.e. you don't care about the above risk) try this pattern instead...

```
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < itemgrid.RowCount - 1; i++ )
            {
                var sInsertSQL = string.Format(@"
insert tbl_godown (
    date,category,product,quantity,MRP,salesrate,margin,Total,vendor,unit
    )
    values(
        '{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}',{5},{6},{7},{8},{9}
        )'",
                    itemgrid.Rows[i].Cells["Column1"].Value,
                    itemgrid.Rows[i].Cells["Column2"].Value,
                    itemgrid.Rows[i].Cells["Column3"].Value,
                    itemgrid.Rows[i].Cells["Column4"].Value,
                    Convert.ToDouble(itemgrid.Rows[i].Cells["Column5"].Value),
                    Convert.ToDouble(itemgrid.Rows[i].Cells["Column6"].Value),
                    Convert.ToDouble(itemgrid.Rows[i].Cells["Column7"].Value),
                    Convert.ToDouble(itemgrid.Rows[i].Cells["Column8"].Value),
                    Convert.ToDouble(itemgrid.Rows[i].Cells["Column9"].Value),
                    Convert.ToDouble(itemgrid.Rows[i].Cells["Column10"].Value)
                    );
                dru.insertdata(sInsertSQL);
                MessageBox.Show("Insert Successfully");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

This is a much easier pattern to read/debug.  You can always output sInsertSQL to the immediate pane and then copy/paste into SSMS to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: +1 for using String.Format.  Interpolation also works (if you are using the later versions of C# that support it).  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx